# How to use Float arrays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### Why does this not work?

```
     private void RandomTp(IPlayer player) {

            float[] FFATeles = {
                -72.0, 240, 25;
                -97, 240, -30;
                -43, 240, -26;
            }
            Random rand = new Random;
            int index = rand.Next(FFATeles.Length);
            player.Teleport({FFATeles[index]});
        }
```

I'm trying to pull a random coordinate from the float array to teleport the player to. I get his error : IR.cs(123,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'

I'm a bit new to coding and I'm trying to make code teleport the player to one of the random coordinates from the float array but i don't think im doing it right.

Comment: You have semi-colons instead of commas in your array instantiation code.

Comment: Additionally, it's not clear what you expect the curly braces within `player.Teleport({FFATeles[index]});` to do - perhaps you just meant `player.Teleport(FFATeles[index]);`? (I don't know what `player.Teleport` expects as an argument...)

Comment: Next, the type of `-72.0` is `double`, not `float` - if you want a `float`, you'll need a suffix: `-72.0f` (or just use -72).

Comment: Are you sure you need a float array at all, given that all your values are integers?

Answer (score 1):

You overall idea is good, but there were quite a few syntax errors. Here is a cleaned up version:

```
private void RandomTp(IPlayer player)
{

    float[] FFATeles =
    {
        -72.0f, 240f, 25f,
        -97f, 240f, -30f,
        -43f, 240f, -26f
    };
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next(FFATeles.Length);
    player.Teleport(FFATeles[index]);
}
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)

Answer (score -1):

I would say the problem is your array

Splitting your array in multiple lines for better readability is really nice, but using semicolon as separator is not correct.

```cs
float[] FFATeles = {
        -72.0, 240, 25; <-- semicolon instead of comma
        -97, 240, -30; <--
        -43, 240, -26; <--
}
```

So swap them out with commas:

```cs
float[] FFATeles = {
        -72.0, 240, 25,
        -97, 240, -30,
        -43, 240, -26,
}
```

Also when you create your `Random` object, you are missing parentheses `()`
So change this line:

```cs
Random rand = new Random;
```

To this line:

```cs
Random rand = new Random();
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)